# Trying to set an environment variable in node? not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, config

**So I have install npm `config` module.**

**I have trying to set a local variable that stores a secret/privateKey.**

Tried setting an environment variable/private key using the following command

```
 export VIDLY_JWTPRIVATEKEY=MYSECUREKEY
```

however it don't think It is being set as I get an error via

```
console.log("FATAL ERROR: JWTPRIVATEKEY is not defined");
```

This is how I am checking if the key is set..

index.js

```
if (!config.get("JWTPRIVATEKEY")) {
  console.log("FATAL ERROR: JWTPRIVATEKEY is not defined");
  // node environment variable. 1 (any other number exc. 0) is exit the app, 0 is success
  process.exit(1);
}
```

userAuth.js  I once again try to get the private, however its not set (?)

```
   #code above 

  const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, config.get("JWTPRIVATEKEY"));
```

default.json (in config module folder)

```
{
  "JWTPRIVATEKEY": ""
}
```

**custom-environment-variables.json (in config folder)**

```
{
  "JWTPRIVATEKEY": "VIDLY_JWTPRIVATEKEY"
}
```

**

> ERROR: "FATAL ERROR: JWTPRIVATEKEY is not defined"

**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I could not get if the question is about environment variables or config file.

Comment: *in config module folder*? The **json** files should be in `./config/*.json`also if you want to use js export it like `module.exports = {"JWTPRIVATEKEY": "VIDLY_JWTPRIVATEKEY"}` - The docs are extensive https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki

Comment: No the config module is an npm package, and the file is suppose to be setup up like they are... i.e. no need to export module.... i reckon the local variable is not being set ?

Comment: @vahdet updated the question for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting the variable with this way, you can try to set it in production and development config folders like this:

**config/development.js**

```
const config = {
    env: 'development',
    JWTPRIVATEKEY: <your_dev_key>
};

module.exports = config;
```

**config/production.js**

```
const config = {
    env: 'production',
    JWTPRIVATEKEY: <your_prod_key>
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: great! What would be the command line for setting the environment variable with this approach please?

Comment: Personally I just use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). After install it you can set `JWT_KEY='<your_key>'` in a `.env` file at your root project. Then complete your development/production config file like this: `JWTPRIVATEKEY: process.env.JWT_KEY`.

Answer (score 0):

it is two years later! but i think it can be useful, atleast for others.
if you set environment variable AND run the app in IDE's Terminal, it will not work!
but if do these in "cmd", it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).